# Liquibase execution order in Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, liquibase

I was using spring-boot 1.0.1 and everything was fine.

Than I needed to upgrade to latest version 1.1.8.

As I see something with liquibase is changed and I cannot run application in the development mode normally.

The problem is that before updating first Hibernate was creating tables and performing database things, then Liquibase. Now Liquibase runs first and complains that there is no tables.

Is there a way how to solve this?

Comment: It works in all the tests and samples. But the implementation changed since 1.0. It might help if you share your code (or even better a minimal project that illustrates the problem).

Comment: Yes it works, but in the order which is not suitable for me. There is nothing to share, but I have found that in LiquibaseAutoConfiguration defines that EntityManager depends on Liquibase, so there is nothing much I can do to change order. Idea was to set liquibase.enabled=false and call the bean later but with that property bean is not even initialized.